# Access: How to insert a new line under control source for a text box?

Tags: ms-access

I have two pieces of information which I would like to display together in one (not two) text box but in different lines on a report, e.g.:

```
FirstName
LastName
```

To have both information in one line I could use something like that under control source of the text box:

[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]

But by what do I need to substitute " " to get into a new line?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below expression.

```
=[FirstName] & Chr(13)+Chr(10) & [LastName]
```